# How to trigger a password confirmation method to a class in javascript, every time one of the other methods is called?

Tags: javascript

Fellow programmers,
sorry for the badly asked question, but i am new to programming and this is part of a homework that i can't figure out. The condition in the task goes like this..

I have an abstract class representing a notebook - AbstractNotebook, it has methods like:

```
-addTextToPage();
-deleteTextFromPage();
-read();...
```

i want to inherit from that class into a class that represents a ProtectedNotebook, all being the same as in the AbstractNotebook class, except that, it has a password, defined with the creation of a new instance and the actual thing i have no idea how to do:

every time a method is called in an instance ot the ProtectedNotebook class, first i have to make the user write the password for that instance and then the actual method could continue.

//My abstract class is:

```
function AbstractNotepad () {
    if (this.constructor.name == 'AbstractNotepad') {
        throw new Error('This class is abstract and cannot be instanciated');
    }
}

AbstractNotepad.prototype.getPages = function() {
    return this.pages;
};

AbstractNotepad.prototype.insertPage = function(page) {
    if(page instanceof Page){
        this.pages.push(page);
    }
};
AbstractNotepad.prototype.getPageNumber = function() {
    return getPages()[pageNumber - 1];
};
AbstractNotepad.prototype.addTextToPage = function(pageNumber, textToAdd) {
    this.getPageNumber().setText(this.getPageNumber().getText() + ' ' + textToAdd);
};

AbstractNotepad.prototype.swapTextInPage = function(pageNumber, text) {
    this.getPageNumber().deleteText();
    this.getPageNumber().setText(text);
};

AbstractNotepad.prototype.deleteTextFromPage = function(pageNumber) {
    this.getPageNumber().deleteText();
};

AbstractNotepad.prototype.readNotebook = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.getPages().length; i++) {
        console.log((i + 1) + '\n' + this.getPages()[i].read())
    }
}
```

//The actual ProtectedNotebook class is at the moment:

```
var moduleSecure = (function(){ 
    function SecuredNotepad (pass) {
        this.pages = [];
        var password = pass;
        this.getPass=function(){  //obviously left for debugging purposes
            return password;
        }

    }
    SecuredNotepad.prototype = Object.create(AbstractNotepad.prototype);
    SecuredNotepad.prototype.constructor = SecuredNotepad;

    return {
        createNotebook: function(pass){
            var reg = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{5,}/; 

            if(!reg.test(pass)){
                throw new Error('password is not valid');
            }
            return new SecuredNotepad(pass);
        }
    }

})();
```

Is this actualy possible? Or i have to override completely all the methods, just to add the confimation part to them?
Thak you in advance!
Kristian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the secure notebook object by looping over the functions in the regular notebook prototype and wrapping them in a password validation function.

Here's a password wrapper prototype:

```
function pwdProtect(validator, successFunc, failFunc) {
  return function() {
    if (validator()) {
        return successFunc.apply(null, arguments);
    } else {
        return failFunc.apply(null, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

It takes three arguments, a validator function that will return either true or false and a pair of functions, one run on success, one run on failure. It returns a function. Any arguments passed to the wrapper are passed, in turn, to the wrapped functions (either success or failure, whichever is triggered).

```
function SecureNotebook() {
  for (var attr in Notebook.prototype) {
    if (Notebook.prototype.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      if (typeof Notebook.prototype[attr] == 'function') {
        this[attr] = pwdProtect(pwdPlaceHolder, Notebook.prototype[attr], alwaysFalse);
      } else {
        this[attr] = Notebook.prototype[attr];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the function for the SecureNotebook constructor. It clones the attributes of the regular Notebook prototype and, if they're functions, wraps them in the pwdProtect for validation and protection. The functions I pass in the example are just simple placeholders.

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5utguu1j/

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Todd! I needed a little time to get a grasp of the concept (never would have tought about doing that myself), but i've managed to implement it. Cheers!